# NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No qualifying bean of type available: expected at least 1 bean which qualifies as autowire candidate

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, autowired, external-dependencies

I am trying to migrate a Spring 4.x.x to Spring boot and it has a dependency on a class in external spring 2.5 jar. I have made all the autowiring changes and below is my application class

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan(basePackages = { "com.xyz" })
public class MainApiApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MainApiApplication.class, args);
    }
}
```

The dependent class in the external jar is present under the package com.xyz.abc because of which I have placed my main application class under com.xyz package and also added the component scan under the same package

Here are my component classes with the dependency autowired

```
@Component
public class ComponentClassA {
    @Autowired
    private ComponentClassB currencyService;
}

@Component
public class ComponentClassB {

    @Autowired
    private DependentClass depClass;
}
```

DependentClass is the class present in the external dependent jar which I have locally attached and built

When building the application, compilation of all files is fine and build is generated successfully. But when I start the application, I get the below error

```
 Field DependentClass in com.xyz.ComponentClassB required a bean of type 'com.xyz.common.util.DependentClass' that could not be found.
```

I don't understand the reason for the class from external jar being not found as I have added component scan for the package

The definition of DependentClass is like below

```
public class DependentClass extends ResourceClass<Map<String, Double>> {
            // Methods and logic
}
```

Is it because DependentClass is extending a class ? Can someone help me figure out the reason for the error ?

Comment: Does your `DependentClass` exist as a Bean within the Spring context (either xml or `@Bean` annotation)?

Comment: No it does not exist. It is just part of the jar

Comment: It should be a bean then only Auto wiring will work. Better to create a bean in you @Configuration file and then do Autowiring.

Comment: Yes, as others mentioned, it should be registered as a Bean then. If you don't / can't modify the classes in the .jar file, I would suggest using xml configuration

Comment: use @Bean
   public DependentClass depClass(){
    return new DependentClass();
   }

Answer (score 6):

The `DependentClass` does not have `@Component` annotation on it. So, you need to create a bean of `DependentClass` yourself either via XML or Java config.

And it is not necessary that you place your main class under the same package as `DependentClass`.

Answer (score 1):

Define your class as per below:-

```
     @Component("depClass") 
     public class DependentClass extends ResourceClass<Map<String, Double>> {
            // Methods and logic
      }
```

Component register it into your context defination if this package lie into your ScanBasePackages and the **depClass** inside the component annotation define the name of your bean.

you can also call it by:-

```
    @Autowired
    @Qualifier("depClass")
    private DependentClass dependentClass;
```

If that class define in your external class then use @Bean annotaion like:-

```
 @Bean
   public DependentClass depClass(){
    return new DependentClass();
   }
```

After that Autowired the class you get the instance finally.

Comment: This way by defining the already existing class from the jar, I am duplicating it know! Is this the only way ?

Comment: As per my perspective this is the only way that i use,may be there are more things to define the class.If i find another way then i also share with you.

Answer (score 0):

DependentClass is not defined in your current Spring Context.DependentClass is not annotated with a bean (@Bean).Hence **nosuchbeandefinitionexception** occurs.

```
@Bean
public class DependentClass extends ResourceClass<Map<String, Double>> {
            // Methods and logic
}
```

Comment: `@Bean` annotation is not allowed on classes or interfaces; the code you pasted will not compile